# WPF ListBox select word with mouse

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox

Is it possible to select single words with the mouse in a WPF ListBox control? When yes, how can I do that?

All hints are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

If you define an `ItemTemplate` for your `ListBox`, you can use a `TextBox` to display each item (assuming that your items are plain `string`s):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

I just tested it and had to make one change to set the `Binding.Mode` property to `OneWay` and it worked just fine. However, I noticed that the `TextBox` would stop each item from being selected, so added a `Style` to take care of that and styled the items a little bit too:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}" Name="ListBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ., Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True">
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="TextBox.BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ListBox.IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.IsSelected" Value="True" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: That is what I did. But when I select a item with the mouse, than I select the whole item line in the ListBox and not a single word.